# Azure Monitor Log Search no events between times

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, kusto-explorer

I am logging shipping notices to log analytics. Shipping is only done between 9am and 5pm Monday to Friday.  I want to trigger an alert if no orders are dispatched in that window for 2 hours.

I have identified all orders binned by hour

```
BoomiOrderTracking_CL
| where  MessageType_s  == 'Order Dispatch Invoice'
| summarize invoices = count () by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

| TimeGenerated | invoices |
| --- | --- |
| 14/09/2023, 09:00:00.000 | 37 |
| 14/09/2023, 10:00:00.000 | 35 |
| 14/09/2023, 11:00:00.000 | 40 |

I think I need to generate a dummy dataset for hours out side of working time with a default value so that the alter will ignore those values.

Is this the best approach?  If so how do I generate the dummy data?

I have tried to do make-series to generate the dummy data but I cant use that function with a two column data set.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a field that indicates whether alert is being evaluated during business hours and use that while setting up the alert:

```sql
BoomiOrderTracking_CL
| where  MessageType_s  == 'Order Dispatch Invoice'
| extend isWithinBusinessHours = toint(format_timespan(dayofweek(TimeGenerated), "d")) between (1..5) and datetime_part("hour", TimeGenerated) between (9..17)
| summarize invoices = count () by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), isWithinBusinessHours
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

I want to point you to an alternative of fixing this in KQL: create an [alert processing rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-processing-rules?tabs=portal) suppresses action groups by specifying a recurrence during which action groups are suppressed

> You can use alert processing rules to add action groups or remove (suppress) action groups from your fired alerts.

Here is schedule that could work for your use case.

[image]

(I've setup 2 recurrences, one for the weekends and one for the non-business hours)